# Joomla Component Creating an override for the trash button

Tags: joomla, components

I'm trying to override the trash button in the administrator back end in Joomla

I'm putting into the controller:

```
    public function trash( $task = 'trash', $alt = 'trash', $check = true ){
      echo "here";
       exit();
     }
```

(I've also tried it with task = remove)

But I can't get it to work.  Joomla ignores this and simply deletes the field.

I've already put in a save override and save2copy but I can't figure out why this won't work.  Can someone help?

thanks

Comment: It would be good if you would give a little more context. Are you overriding a core component? Or are you overriding trash in your own component?

Comment: sorry should have said it's my own component.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - thanks to those who've thought about it.

I'd used an auto component generator and when they had created the class they hadn't included a constructor function.  So I added one and it now works fine.

Comment: Was it www.component-creator.com? 
I would like to report the bug :)

Comment: hi it was component - creator  - I created two views

Comment: Unless you created empty views (which are, by definition, empty), it should work right away. It would be great if you could send a ticket to https://www.component-creator.com/en/help/contact with more details.

Comment: it's not an empty view but I'm happy to create a ticket and you're welcome to try it for yourself